# Providing Apple Login from a Swift Package

Tags: ios, swift, apple-login, asauthorizationcontroller

Our team is attempting to break up our monolithic app into Swift Package components.

One of the elements we are migrating is our Authentication Systems.

We're running into a particular issue with Apple, where the exact same code executed in the app works, but in the swift package it does not.

In both scenarios, the log in function fires and the user can choose to log in, but when that code lives in a Swift Package, the `ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential` delegate callback never fires.

The login is still working, as the app changes the Apple Login UI to show an existing user sign in, I just never get the credential data.

The code in question is below, and it revolves around the `ASAuthorizationController`. If that object is instantiated in the App, even if it is passed as a parameter to the Swift Package the login will succeed and the delegate will fire. It's as though it's silently pulling some local environment element when it's created.

Is there a way I can pass a UIWindow or UIViewController to the AuthenticationServices pipeline (as GoogleSignIn allows) so that the logic can reside in a package?

```
// 1. Assign the Listeners that will handle the responses
signInWithAppleViewModel = SignInWithAppleViewModel()
// 2. Instantiate the AuthorizationAppleIDProvider
let provider = ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider()
// 3. Create a request with the help of provider - ASAuthorizationAppleIDRequest
let request = provider.createRequest()
// 4. Scope to contact information to be requested from the user during authentication.
request.requestedScopes = [.fullName, .email]
// 5. A controller that manages authorization requests created by a provider.
let controller = ASAuthorizationController(authorizationRequests: [request])
// 6. Set delegate to perform action
controller.delegate = signInWithAppleViewModel
// 7. Initiate the authorization flows.
controller.performRequests()
```

Comment: I do not think it makes sense to put apple sign in in a dependency, much less a SPM package. The credentials are populated only once, and they need to be stored locally or remotely to be accessible again. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/implementing_user_authentication_with_sign_in_with_apple

Comment: I can see that point of view. We put our persistence layer in a Swift Package, and we're using a Common package to store protocols that allow for concrete data contracts. We're wrapping Google, Apple, and Facebook login in a protocol backed function that maps returned user data to a simple data transfer object and I would love to be able to reuse that implementation across apps. Going to keep trying.

Comment: Our team managed to accomplish moving the sign-in flow to a Swift Package on both iOS + macOS. If you're interested how the sign-in works, you can check out the authentication code [here](https://github.com/Flowductive/easy-firebase/blob/ea951636547797ee4c7984c8071c217f34ee925a/Sources/EasyFirebase/Services/Auth/EasyAuth.swift#L395-L407).

Comment: @BenMyers This works. If you want to submit an answer, and specifically call out implementing `ASAuthorizationControllerPresentationContextProviding` and overriding `public func presentationAnchor(for controller: ASAuthorizationController) -> ASPresentationAnchor` I would award the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My team wrote a package that includes this functionality, called [EasyFirebase](https://github.com/Flowductive/easy-firebase). This package allows single-line code for sign-in with Apple on iOS 11.0+ and macOS 10.15+.

To do this, follow the steps using the article [here](https://github.com/Flowductive/easy-firebase/wiki/Implement-Sign-in-With-Apple). As usual, you'll need the "Sign in with Apple" capability in your Xcode project, an email relay key in your [Apple Developer account](https://developer.apple.com/account/), and the Swift package itself, with installation instructions [here](https://github.com/Flowductive/easy-firebase/wiki/Installation).

If you don't want to use the package, you can check out some [sample code](https://github.com/Flowductive/easy-firebase/blob/ea951636547797ee4c7984c8071c217f34ee925a/Sources/EasyFirebase/Services/Auth/EasyAuth.swift#L395-L407) to implement Sign in With Apple the way you specified. If you do, you'll need to implement `ASAuthorizationControllerPresentationContextProviding` and override `presentationAnchor(for:)` in your code:

```swift
public func presentationAnchor(for controller: ASAuthorizationController) -> ASPresentationAnchor {
  ASPresentationAnchor()
}

public func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithAuthorization authorization: ASAuthorization) {
  if let appleIDCredential = authorization.credential as? ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential {
    guard let nonce = currentNonce else { ... }
    guard let appleIDToken = appleIDCredential.identityToken else { ... }
    guard let idTokenString = String(data: appleIDToken, encoding: .utf8) else { ... }
    let credential = OAuthProvider.credential(withProviderID: "apple.com", idToken: idTokenString, rawNonce: nonce)
    // ...
  }
}

public func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithError error: Error) {
  // An error occured...
}
```